# ML-Agents AddVectorObs parameter question

Tags: unity-game-engine, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

I want observe bool value in AddVectorObs...

but i don't know how.

is there other function for observe bool values?

this is my values

```
public bool target1_eaten = false;
public bool target2_eaten = false;
public bool target3_eaten = false;
```

I want my AI-learning observe those values.. help me plz

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following code in your Agent class and increase your Vector Observation Space Size by 3 on the Behavior Parameters in the Unity Editor.

```
public override void CollectObservations()
{
    AddVectorObs(target1_eaten);
    AddVectorObs(target1_eaten);
    AddVectorObs(target1_eaten);
}
```